# Ark: Survival Evolved. Deleting a tribe and structures using admin commands

Tags: server-administration, ark-survival-evolved

I have an Ark Server.

When I started I created a tribe Called `KIV`. For some reason the tribe governance was all messed up and all my Dinos and Structures belonged to the tribe and not to me, it wouldn't allow me to ride dino's or enter my structures.

I then changed the governance so that everything is player owned and not tribe owned, I clicked on `Set Tribe Governance`, but this didn't solve the problem.

So I left the tribe, this made things even worse because now all the structures belong to a tribe with no one in it.

I used the `admincheat givetome` to get all my dinos and structures back, but now when I want to build around that area it keeps telling me I'm too close to an enemy tribe.

So how do I delete/merge a tribe using admin commands in Ark?

I have full access to the FTP server to change `ini` files and a admin CMS hosted by Nitrado.

I don't want to delete the tribe file using FTP because that might make the game glitch if there are structures left belonging to that empty tribe. (In case I missed one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the admin command `GiveAllStructure` to give yourself the building piece you are looking at, and all connected buildings.

If this doesn't work, look at a piece of building, belonging to the original tribe and try to use `TakeAllStructure`.  You can repeat the process on a dino with `TakeAllDino`.  These will change the ownership to your current tribe.

Note that if you want everything in the original tribe, you should first target something belonging to the original tribe and use the following commands:

1. `ForcePlayerToJoinTargetTribe`  (You can get PlayerID from `ShowMyAdminManager`
2. `MakeTribeAdmin` (May be redundant)
3. `MakeTribeFounder`

At which point, you would use the originally mentioned commands on the structures/dinos that no longer belong to the tribe.  (Make sure to set tribe permissions before doing any of it, this time.)

Hopefully this helps getting everything back to normal.

(Sidenote:  You'll need to precede each command with `admincheat`, so I didn't mention it over and over.)